# Reading changes with dbf library in python

Tags: python, mysql, dbf

I am trying to make a program that takes changes in a `dbf` file then uploads them. I have got it to read the `dbf` file and upload them to a `mysql` database but its a 50 minuite upload. I have tried to get it to only upload fields that have been changed. The problem I have is that it seems i need to close and re-open the `dbf` file. If someone makes a change whilst its doing this, it doesnt notice theres been a change.

Is there a better/right way of doing this:

```
import time
import dbf
import MySQLdb
import os

source_path = r"\\path\to\file"
file_name = "\\test.Dbf"

print "Found Source DBF"

source = dbf.Table(source_path + file_name)
source.open()

print "Opened DBF"

updated = list(source)
print "Copied Source"

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "myHost.com", port=3306, user = "user", passwd = "pass", db = "database")
cur = db.cursor()
print "Connected to database"

try:
        cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbftomysql")
except:
        db.rollback()

print "Dropped old table"

sql = """CREATE TABLE table(
        col1 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        col2 VARCHAR(200),
        col3 VARCHAR(200),
        col4 NUMERIC(15,2),
        col5 VARCHAR(200) )"""

cur.execute(sql)

print "Created new table"

for i, s in zip(source, updated):
        query = """INSERT table SET col1 = %s, col2 = %s, col3 = %s, col4 = %s, col5 = %s"""
        values = (i["col1"], i ["col2 "], i["col3"], i["col4"], i["col5"])
        cur.execute(query, values)
        db.commit()
        print i["col1"], i ["col2 "], i["col3"], i["col4"], i["col5"]
print "First Upload Completed"

while True:
        for i, s in zip(source, updated):
                if i["col1"] != s["col1"]:
                        print i["col1"] + " col1Updated"
                        query = """UPDATE table SET col1= %s WHERE col1= %s"""
                        values = (i["col1"], s["col1"])
                        try:
                                cur.execute(query, values)
                                db.commit()
                        except:
                                db.rollback()
                                print "No connection to database"

                if i["col2"] != s["col2"]:
                        print i["col2"] + " col2 Updated for " + i["col1"]
                        query = """UPDATE table SET col2 = %s WHERE col1= %s OR col1= %s"""
                        values = (i["col2"], i["col1"], s["col1"])
                        try:
                                cur.execute(query, values)
                                db.commit()
                        except:
                                db.rollback()
                                print "No connection to database"
                        #ect

        updated = list(source)
        source.close()
        source.open()                     
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dbf` library will only fetch the record from the dbf file if it doesn't already exist in memory; when you do

```
updated = list(source)
```

you are effectively freezing all the rows because `updated` is a list of records (not a list of `list`s or a list of `tuple`s; this means that when you later try to compare `source` and `updated` you are comparing the same data.

In order to make `updated` be a separate entity from `source` try

```
updated = [tuple(row) for row in source]
```

which will give you a list of tuples, or

```
updated = [scatter(row, dict) for row in source]
```

which will give you a list of dicts, which is what you need for your field comparison code further down.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added that and I now get an error. `tuple indices must be integers, not str`. I sort of understand what it is telling me but not how to implement it. Also after the field has been uploaded would i need to do something like `s['col1'] = i['col1']`